# User Input Validation, enforcing a string containing only letters

Tags: java, validation, input

Im trying to make a user input validation system within one of my methods... its working fine to a cetain extent, but despite the code, its still allowing for integers as valid input, which i dont want it to be, how can i alter this code, to ONLY allow letters(strings) as valid input. im baffled at this point, i tried this system for with integers and it works flawlessly but with letters, no avail.

Insight?

```
public class Player {

    private static String userName;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private boolean validInput = false;

    public void createUser(){

        do {
        System.out.println("Please enter you name : ");
                if(scan.hasNextLine()){
                    userName = scan.nextLine();
                    validInput = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You can only use letters!");
                    validInput = false;
                    scan.next();
                }
    } while (!(validInput));
        System.out.println(getUser());
    }
    static void setUser(String userName){
        Player.userName = userName; 
    }
    String getUser(){
        return userName;    
    }

}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you checking that the user entered letters rather than numbers?

Comment: Have you considered regular expressions ?

Comment: yes i want them to only use letters

Comment: dmitry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean what Java provides API to check String content (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and the rules you can specify are very wide - including the absence of any digital symbol. Maybe this is that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
            if(scan.hasNextLine()){
```

with

```
            if(scan.hasNext("\\p{Alpha}*")){
```

If you use `hasNextLine` the scanner merely checks if it has **anything** up next, not particularly for letters or anything else.

When you use a regular expression, in this case `p{Alpha}*` which means "zero or more letters" (but scanner will look for at least one character that is not whitespace, so it's actually "1 or more letters"), the scanner behaves much like it does when you do the same with `hasNextInt()` (which is looking for digits).

Note that it will only accept letters in the US-ASCII range, so no accents or Norse letters or anything like that, just `a-zA-Z`.

Also, read the username with `scan.next()`, not `nextLine()` - though you may want to call `nextLine()` later to clean the rest of the line. If you use `nextLine()` to read the username, there might be something after the letters which is not a letter, and it will be read by `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

add a method to your code to actually scan for numbers...

something like this:

```
private boolean containsNumbers(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (c > 47 && c < 58) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will only look at the first character.

Comment: right :) didnt really check the code :) i've made the change :)

Comment: check now... it's fixed :) just had no need for else statement

Answer (score 0):

Try something like"

```
if (!userName.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
    System.out.println("Only strings no numbers");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will take the code from Ubica. You can do it also like this. It is readable:

```java
private boolean containsNumbers(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```